# If an app is open , don't open it again, just switch to the app in tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am making a program in Tkinter and I realized that after converting the app to exe, If I double click the program it will open the program again even when it's already opened
so how to make it detect if the program is open and if the user tried to open it again it will just focus on the program window instead of opening it again ?

I saw two questions with answers but neither one of them is to Tkinter library

Comment: What if a user wants to have two instances of the program? What if two users on the same machine want to use the program?

Comment: The program is not designed to open it 2 times, and if someone switch to another user he can open it again because it won't be open from the start , an example https://drive.google.com/open?id=108LmEkWCBkDQZBKhKwHQmCaav5VF6bvH&authuser=ahmadhk2003%40gmail.com&usp=drive_fs